# Is there any way to implement border-image around the edge of layer (like CSS border-image)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2

I would like to implement a layer that has a border-image pattern like CSS with Swift4.2 but I don't have any idea what to do.

I saw an app named "PriPara" app https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/pripara/id1039257927?mt=8 released in HongKong App Store and it has a UITabBar and a UINavigationBar that have complicated outlines and some image patterns along them. As follows:

[Whole screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRmmL.jpg), [UITabBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOEYp.png), [UINavigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTp3p.png)

The UITabBar has a lace-like image pattern on it's border.
The UINavigationBar has a jewelry-like image on it's border.

I already know I can change the shape of the outline of a layer by modifying the "path" property of CAShapeLayer class, as the website says https://medium.com/@philipp307/draw-a-custom-ios-tabbar-shape-27d298a7f4fa .

But, as for border image, I don't have a clue. Though it looks like CSS has border-image property as the page shows https://css-generator.net/border-image/ , Swift does not. Do I have to use some external libraries, or is there no way to implement this?

Comment: Well, UIKit has nothing for this, as far as I can see. So, CALayer and UIView will be no help. I think that you will need to find an external library. I'm super interested in what you find. Please add a comment here if you find a cocoa-compatible way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... your question is far too broad. The images you've shown may or may not be using `UINavigationBar` and / or `UITabBar`. They may simply be images. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: > Mike Hay Sure.

Comment: >DonMag Sorry, I looked over How to Ask but it looks it did not enough. I once supposed they have used the simple image too, but I'm not sure. I have no idea whether a simple image can fit to the left and right edges of the screen in a way I would like to realize, given that there are various devices in Apple platform whose screen sizes are different each other. I have to try it later on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have basically solved the issue.

I chose the way to use a simple image as DonMag says. Maybe it's too simple but it's all I can.

It uses CAShapeLayer, UIBezierPath.

In original UITabBarController subclass, execute following code:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

//Get CGPath.Original Layer will be expanded lengthwise.
shapeLayer.path = self.createLengthExpandShape()

//Set image
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage.init(named: "MyImage.png")!).cgColor

//Set layer
self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
```

The most tricky point is UIImage.init(colorPattern:). You can use this function to set an image into CAShapeLayer. An image file is used upside down in runtime. So you have to turn it upside down in advance with a paint soft or something. Also, please note the image is put from at the top-left corner of the ORIGINAL(before expanded) layer. If you changed the way to expand CAShapeLayer, you should also adjust the content on the image file.

The image file: https://i.imgur.com/BYnkuXQ

For whole project, see https://github.com/Satoru-PriChan/ChangeUITabBarAppearance

If you like it, click Star in the GitHub project.